# Is there something like Spark's unionByName in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to concatenate tables with different schemas, filling unknown values with `null`.

Simply using `UNION ALL` of course does not work like this:

```sql
WITH
  x AS (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b ),
  y AS (SELECT 3 AS b, 4 AS c )
SELECT * FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM y
```

```
a b
1 2
3 4
```

(unwanted result)

In Spark, I'd use `unionByName` to get the following result:

```
a b c
1 2 
  3 4
```

(wanted result)

Of course, I can manually create the needed query (adding `nulls`s) in BigQuery like so:

```
SELECT a, b, NULL c FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL a, b, c FROM y
```

But I'd prefer to have a generic solution, not requiring me to generate something like that.

So, is there something like `unionByName` in BigQuery? Or can one come up with a generic SQL function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach *(I think it is as generic as one can get)*

```
create temp function json_extract_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";
create temp function json_extract_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";

create temp table temp_table as (
  select json, key, value
  from (
    select to_json_string(t) json from table_x as t
    union all
    select to_json_string(t) from table_y as t
  ) t, unnest(json_extract_keys(json)) key with offset
  join unnest(json_extract_values(json)) value with offset
  using(offset)
  order by key
);

execute immediate(select '''
select * except(json) from temp_table
pivot (any_value(value) for key in ("''' || string_agg(distinct key, '","') || '"))'
from temp_table
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]